# How does EL work with methods and fields of object without knowing its class

Tags: java, jsp, el

I can't understand how it works when we do in jsp something like

```
${someObject.doMethod()}
```

The thing what I don't understand is that we don't define here the class of object but jasper compiles that and this code works.
I mean we don't write

```
${SomeClass someObject.doMethod()}
```

Please, explain how it works.

Comment: If this is a Jasper question, please add the appropriate tag to the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL is using [reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) in the background. So, in your example `someObject` is first taken from the current context (which you can look at as a `Map`), and then the rest of the expression is parsed further. For example, if it ends with `()` then a method with given name is searched on the object. If it was something like `${someObject.someField}`, then a public getter is looked for, named `getSomeField()`, etc.

A good comment by @Prisoner - one important thing to note is that EL is evaluated at runtime. So, you won't get any compiler errors/warnings if objects or methods you use in some expression are actually non existing.

Comment: This is the correct answer, so I don't want to post another one, but I would add that EL is not evaluated at compile time, but rather at run time. So using the example, doMethod() may not exist on the object in question and this would not be handled until it tried to evaluate the expression.

Comment: @Prisoner Thanks, I was actually going to write that also but forgot. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Do I understand you right? You mean, that every time I request certain jsp page (article.jsp for ex) the EL evaluates my expressions and via reflection executes my method?

Comment: Short answer - yes. For example, if you have `<span>${someObject.message}</span>`, and `getMessage()` returns `Hello there!`, it will be rendered as `<span>Hello there!</span>`. But, in JSF for example, if you have `<h:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething()}"`, it won't be executed until you press the button, but that's another story.

Comment: @iJava - that is mostly correct. A jsp page is first compiled into a .java file and then into a .class file which is executed. But when evaluating the EL it uses reflection to find the appropriate method to call and calls it against the object. But the process of creating the .class file does not try to evaluate the type of `someObject` in most cases - it just treats it as an Object that will be passed to the reflection API.